# How to print the value of a column using awk command?

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to write a script that would print the CPU utilisation and memory utilisation result to a csv file. But I would like to only print the values that lie in the specific columns named "CPU", "USERNAME" and "MEMORY".

Could you kindly tell me how can I achieve the same using awk script?Using awk, I have found that awk'{print $2,$5}' prints the values of the 2nd and 5th column. But I would like to print the values by providing the column name instead of the column number.

Is it possible to do that?

The sample script I have written is:

```
#!/bin/sh
#This is a comment
#This is my first shell script
echo "System Status Report"
date
echo "CPU Utilisation Report"
prstat -a > CPU.xls
```

The sample output is:

```
PID USERNAME SIZE RSS STATE PRI NICE TIME CPU PROCESS/NLWP 
26652 root 22M 9648K sleep 1 0 94:34.26 0.2% gpp/1 
26854 root 708M 697M sleep 3 0 36:23.19 0.1% logscan/1 
25167 oracle 1254M 1225M sleep 1 0 14:07.01 0.0% oracle/10 
NPROC USERNAME SIZE RSS MEMORY TIME CPU 
41 root 1000M 834M 1.1% 143:47.47 0.4% 
60 oracle 72G 70G 99% 65:07.13 0.1%
```

I would like to get the following output in the file:

```
USERNAME CPU 
root 0.2%  
root 0.1%
oracle 0.0%  
USERNAME MEMORY 
root 1.1% 
oracle 99%
```

Comment: Can you give example input for your script?

Comment: @hek2mgl:I have provided the sample script

Comment: Try the solution but your cpu.xls file should be correct.

Comment: @San I don't know `prstat`. Can you provide a sample output of the program?

Comment: @hek2mgl - Updated the sample output

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely. This is the solution you can implement. 
Say `temp.tmp` is the file that contains the data.

```
# cat temp.tmp
Sno CPU USERNAME
1 50 foo
2 60 bar
3 65 foobar
```

t.awk has the awk code

```
# cat t.awk
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        ix[$i] = i
     }
}
NR>1 {
    print $ix[c1], $ix[c2]
}
```

Now lets see if it works.

```
# awk -f t.awk c1=CPU c2=USERNAME temp.tmp
50 foo
60 bar
65 foobar
```

I think this is what you want isn't it ?

Comment: @Amanpreet:yes!I wanted this..I will try using the same in the script and see if it works

Comment: @Amanpreet: I tried the above mentioned steps..and it is working..Thanks!

Comment: :Sorry,got your name wrong.But now there is a new problem.If you can see the sample output,the script provided by you works fine for the 1st three records.For the next set of records only the username is published `0.2% root 0.1% root 0.0% oracle USERNAME root oracle`